Why does my VSCode produce garbled executable file names when compiling C source code with Chinese characters as filenames using Mingw64?
Why is it that when I compile C language source code with Chinese characters as filenames in my VSCode, the resulting executable file name turns out to be garbled, but there's no issue when using letters, words, or numbers? I'm compiling with Mingw64.
I attempted compiling C source code in VSCode using Mingw64 with filenames containing Chinese characters. I expected the resulting executable file names to be displayed correctly. However, the actual outcome was that the executable file names appeared as garbled characters.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to add a [mre]. Show us the smallest possible example, and please provide textual content as text/source. Please do not use screenshots.

please provide more info, what is your default encoding, what os version and ...

i suggust using the compiler "MSYS2"

How does this answer the question? Additionally I suggest to use correct orthography. ;-)
